# infinite upper triangular modules has no simple submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $k$ be a field.  Let $R$ be the set of infinite upper triangular matrices (columns and row are indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$) with only finitely many nonzero entries in any row or column.  Then let $V$ be the vector space of infinite column vectors (indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$) with finitely many nonzero entries. Then we can view $V$ as an $R$-module with action given by matrix multiplication.

**Then I would like to show that $V$ has no simple submodules.**

However, to me, this is not intuitively correct. For example, let $W$ consists the vectors with some entries at the first row and zeros elsewhere. Then  $W$ has only finitely many nonzero entries (1 or 0 entry) and it is closed under addition. Also for any $A\in R$, $AW\subseteq W$. So it appears to me that $W$ is a submodule, and it is one-dimensional. So it must be simple.

**What the role of infinity here?**

Because if we consider the finite case (finite upper triangular matrix $R$, finite column vectors space $V$, the submodule $W$ I mentioned before is the only simple submodule of $V$. right?) Why this is not true in infinite case? What I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that you want the rows and columns of your matrices indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$ (that is, bidirectionally infinite matrices)?

Comment: I just checked. You are right, the rows and columns are indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$. But how this helps? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how it helps, but it explains why @rschwieb is getting a different answer.

Comment: For each $g \in \mathbb{Z}$, let $V_g$ be the subspace of $V$ consisting of all vectors $\left(\ldots, v_{-1}, v_0, v_1, \ldots\right)$ such that all $i \geq g$ satisfy $v_i = 0$. The trick is to prove that each nontrivial proper $A$-submodule of $V$ is $V_g$ for some $g \in \mathbb{Z}$. It is clear that none of the $V_g$'s is simple.

Comment: Ah! I think I know what I am messing up. I was assuming that we start from row 1 and goes to infinity (I was assuming col and rows are indexed by natural number!). But we are indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$, so it is not reasonable to start from 1. Thus the submodule I mentioned is not a valid choice! Thanks!!!

Comment: @darijgrinberg Does the way it’s indexed affect its structure? It seems possible but also surprising.

Comment: @rschwieb: The way it's indexed affects its definition, because the definition of "upper-triangular" depends on the ordering of the index set, not just on its cardinality.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I see, indeed. Man, that puts a whole new dimension on infinite matrix rings that I hadn't realized.  I felt like both rings were essentially a directed union of the same collection of rings taken in two separate ways, so I was baffled that they would differ a lot.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Do you happen to know then how hard it is to describe the radical? Also, why not develop your comment into a solution post? I would personally rather have my answer outshone by a better one in the solutions rather than in the comments.

Comment: @rschwieb: Afraid I know nothing about the radical. I'll make a post of my solution, but not before the FPSAC submission deadline tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing everything assuming that the sides of $R$ are indexed by $\mathbb N$, and so are the positions of $V$, and that is how matrix multiplication is defined.

The subspace $\{(\lambda, 0, 0\ldots)^T\mid \lambda \in k\}$ appears to be a simple submodule of $_RV$.

(N.B. At the time of this answer, the indexing by $\mathbb Z$ was not mentioned.)

Comment: Maybe there is a mixup in the problem setup? or maybe I am doing something silly...

Comment: Hi, in fact, the subspace you mentioned is exactly I was guessing to be the simple submodule. But it appears that the rows and columns are indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$, does this condition gives us a different answer?  (sorry I did not mention this earlier...I didn't expect this to be important)

Comment: And I suppose that if we indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, then $\{(\lambda,0,0,\ldots)^T\}$ should be the unique simple submodule?

Comment: @Abigail the indexing issue would be good to clarify. I think the last claim you mentioned is correct.